# i want to place items programatically per row 3 items in android using gridlayout

Tags: android, gridview

this is my code to add items in grid layout[image]

items placing correctly per row 3 items but issue is when i delete item from center position is not clearing. I want to clear position and refresh grid layout

Answer (score 0):

Try calling: `requestLayout()` on your GridLayout after deleting item.